# Any responsive Vue.js carousel gallery plugin (with fancy-box like pop up upon click)?

Tags: vue.js, carousel, gallery

Any responsive Vue.js carousel gallery plugin (with fancy-box like pop up upon click) ?

Till now had almost no problem to find suitable vue.js plugins/components but now I did hit the wall, so I had to use jquery + slick + fancybox, but do not like solution out of vue scope, any hints ?

Looking for

- lazy load
- multiple slides carousel
- centered slides
- loop funkcionality
- reponsivness
- fancybox like zoom or at least compatible with any vue fancybox like
  plugin

I tried 'vue-awesome-swiper' but sadly lazy load with 'loop' is bugged in there, also 'loop' generated slides ignore any fancybox callbacks, so couldn't use it much, and also couldn't find any similar alternative to that, even when there are plenty of vue carousals struggling
 to find one I need.

My goal is one row 4 slides carousel image gallery.

Comment: Maybe slick or one of the others here?
http://voidcanvas.com/5-vuejs-image-sliderscarousels-with-demo/

Comment: Hi tnx for response, i tried all of those, only vue-slick is good enough but still dependant on jquery like classic slick, and had a little trouble to find cdn installation link (am using vue in wordpress) , slick itself does not have fancybox option so would also have figure some way of some vue-fancy box. In cassual jquery/slick/fancy its super easy - https://codepen.io/fancyapps/pen/pdbrjx , looking for similar solution in vue only.